# How to update a JLabel text?

Tags: java, string, swing, jlabel

I am making a Hangman game and one of the things I want to make is `JLabel` text , which updates with `ex."_ _ _ _ "`, depending on word.

I can share code if you want.

Comment: This question shows very little research effort. Try visiting the faq [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to learn how to ask better questions, and this in turn will make others more willing to help.

Answer (score 10):

Try using `setText();` with your `JLabel`.

Answer (score 6):

JLabel.setText("ex."+text);
super.update(this.getGraphics());

Comment: You should really add some explanation as to why this code should work - you can also add comments in the code itself - in its current form, it does not provide any explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question.

Comment: All I can really say is that it the code that I posted works. I tried all the solutions above and none of them worked. I am a Java beginner, so I could not really say why it works. But I was having the same issues about the JLabel not updating, and for some reason only my code works on my PC.

Answer (score 4):

This will create a new jLabel and set its text.

```
JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setText("____");
```

You will need to add this label to something [like a JFrame](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/JFramewithLabelandWindowListenertoHandleClosingtheFrame.htm).

If you want to quick and easy, here is the code to make a simple window with a label.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class App {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing Frame");

    JLabel label = new JLabel("This is a Swing frame", JLabel.CENTER);
    label.setText("____");  // Look familiar?  <----------

    frame.add(label);

    frame.setSize(350, 200); // width=350, height=200
    frame.setVisible(true); // Display the frame
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To update the text in a label you use `label.setText("New text")`.

However, without seeing the code, it's hard to say why it doesn't update, as there may be other things wrong.

Comment: @user2511414, no, you never need to invoke repaint() after doing setText(). The setText() method does this for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void updatemylabel(String text){

JLabel.setText("ex."+text);

//place this method inside your Jframe class extend from javax.swing.Jframe
}
```

Comment: Nice If i called from my main i think  ill get error "non static method cannot be referenced from a static context java" 
Where from i ll be able to call this method?
i have  a basic project with gui and a class with main...
Thanks