# How to create error message if text field isn't a numeric value?

Tags: java, swing, integer, jlabel, jtextfield

I'm trying to create a Concert ticket order form for a class assignment and want is so if they don't type a number in the Quantity field it sets a label to "Na" and if it is a numeric value it sets that label to the numeric value. I'm still new at Java and don't know what to do.

How to create error message if text field isn't a numeric value?

Comment: First check if the value in the `Quantity` field is a number or not, then based on the check just made, [set the label text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456401/how-to-update-a-jlabel-text) accordingly.

Comment: thanks but I just don't know how I would go about checking if it is a number or not

Comment: Well, first of all, you have to make the user insert a value, somehow, then store the value of the jlabel in a string using the [getText()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#getText()) method, then... You have to manage this string...

Comment: ok I get that but my issue is what code to use to check the difference between a numeric value and a word or letter

Comment: When a program is expecting a number, it is often better to offer the user a `JSpinner` that uses a `SpinnerNumberModel`. Not only will the model ***always*** be a number, but it will be easier for the user and format the number the way the user expects to see it. *"don't type a number .. it sets a label to "Na""* 1) Use an invalid number as the default & check for that. EG *"Number of items added to cart must be greater than 0!"* 2)  'Na'? I'd understand 'No' or 'NaN' (Not a Number) easier. But make the error message longer and more descriptive. *"Range must be between 1-10 items!"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution after the discussion in the comments...

To check if the string (`test`) written inside the jlabel is a number or not, I used the `Integer.parseInt()` function, which throws "`NumberFormatException`" if this string is not convertible into a numeric value, an Integer in particular.

### Solution

```
JLabel jLabel1 = new JLabel();
String test = jLabel2.getText();
try {
      // Converts the string into a number
      int value = Integer.parseInt(test);
      // Set this number into the jlabel
      jlabel1.setText(""+value);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) { 
      jLabel1.setText("Na");
}
```

If you don't know how to use the `try-catch`, take a look at this: [The try block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html).

Comment: it didn't seem to work I think i did something wrong here is my code try {
      int value = Integer.parseInt(txtQuantity.getText());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) { 
      lblQuantityOutput.setText("Na");
}

Comment: It didn't work because I forget to put the instruction `jlabel.setText(""+value);` which set the value or "Na" in the label you want. Check my code now.

Comment: for "value" do I just enter value or should i put something in place of that

Comment: The int value I created after the try: `int value = Integer.parseInt(test);`.
If this helps, then resolve your question please, thanks!