# How to implement Time and Date methods using Calendar?

Tags: java, date, user-interface, time, calendar

I am trying to make a digital clock which shows the time and date of the system using Java Swing components but I don't know how to implement `Date` and time to it.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class DigitalTimer implements ActionListener {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("DiGi ClOcK");
    JLabel l;
    JLabel l2;

    public DigitalTimer() {
        f.setSize(250, 150);
        Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.ITALIC, 24);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel clk = new JPanel();
        clk.setLayout(new BoxLayout(clk, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        f.add(clk);
        l = new JLabel();
        l2 = new JLabel();
        clk.add(l2);
        clk.add(l);
        Timer refresher = new Timer(1000, this);
        refresher.start();
        l2.setFont(font);
        l2.setText("HH:MM:SS");
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DigitalTimer dTimer;
        dTimer = new DigitalTimer();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        f.setVisible(true);
        Font font1=new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,26);
        Calendar calendar;
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        l.setFont(font1);
        calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) ;  
        calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) ;
        calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    }
}
```

I am unable to call the methods that are in `Calender`. How do I do that?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Please when asking people on Stack Overflow to read your code, indent it properly. This time I had my Eclipse do it for us. Your IDE too will be happy to do it next time.

Comment: *"I don't know how to implement date and time method to it"* This is something you could (read *should*) work out in  a command line app. Once sorted using `System.out.print(..)`, it should be easy to transfer to a `JLabel` or similar. [tag:swing] tag removed, and .. what does this have to do with [tag:jsf]?!? Please choose more relevant tags in future. Both removed.

Comment: can you please upvote the question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We’re picky here, we require an effort from users posting. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) You haven’t shown your effort to search and research your question or your own attempt to solve it. I didn’t downvote, but the question would need some improvement before I can consider upvoting.

Comment: Always search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting. Getting the current time-of-day, generating text to represent that time, and displaying text in Swing are topics that have all been addressed many times on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `LocalTime.now(ZoneId)` to obtain the current time. If you want the time in the default time zone of your JVM, pass `ZoneId.systemDefault()` as argument to the method.
2. Use a `DateTimeFormatter` for formatting the time into a string for display to the user. I suggest `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)`.
3. Call `setText()` on one of your `JLabel`s (`l` or `l2`) to display the string in that label.

**Links**

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [How to update a JLabel text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456401/how-to-update-a-jlabel-text)

Answer (score 0):

The methods indeed are being called, the problem is you aren't updating the `l2` JLabel.
I've modified your code, it does display the time now

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        f.setVisible(true);
        Font font1=new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,26);
        Calendar calendar;
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        l.setFont(font1);
        // Added code below
        int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) ;  
        int min = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) ;
        int sec =calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        l2.setText("Time is " + hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec);
    }
}
```