# 1 Week Countdown Timer in Java

Tags: java, swing, time, timer, countdown

EDIT:
I have created a countdown timer, however I cannot figure out how to update without creating a new instance. The code is below:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS;
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MINUTES;
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.HOURS;
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.DAYS;

public class Countdown {
static int countdownStarterD = 7;
static int countdownStarterH = 24;
static int countdownStarterM = 60;
static int countdownStarterS = 60;
String cSD = Integer.toString(countdownStarterD);
String cSH = Integer.toString(countdownStarterH);
String cSM = Integer.toString(countdownStarterM);
String cSS = Integer.toString(countdownStarterS);
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JLabel days = new JLabel(cSD);
JLabel hours = new JLabel(cSH);
JLabel minutes = new JLabel(cSM);
JLabel seconds = new JLabel(cSS);

public Countdown() {
    panel.add(days);
    panel.add(hours);
    panel.add(minutes);
    panel.add(seconds);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setTitle("Countdown Timer");
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    final Runnable days = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            System.out.println(countdownStarterD);
            countdownStarterD--;

            if (countdownStarterD < 0) {
                countdownStarterD = 6;
            }
        }
    };
    final Runnable hours = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            System.out.println(countdownStarterH);
            countdownStarterH--;

            if (countdownStarterH < 0) {
                countdownStarterH = 23;
            }
        }
    };
    final Runnable minutes = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            System.out.println(countdownStarterM);
            countdownStarterM--;

            if (countdownStarterM < 0) {
                countdownStarterM = 59;
            }
        }
    };
    final Runnable seconds = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            System.out.println(countdownStarterS);
            countdownStarterS--;

            if (countdownStarterS < 0) {
                countdownStarterS = 59;
            }
        }
    };
    final Runnable gui = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new Countdown();
            
        }
    };
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(days, 0, 1, DAYS);
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(hours, 0, 1, HOURS);
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(minutes, 0, 1, MINUTES);
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(seconds, 0, 1, SECONDS);
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(gui, 0, 1, SECONDS);
    
}
```

}

OLD:
I am trying to create a simple GUI timer that counts down from 1 week and restarts once it is finished, it doesn't need to run anything just show a countdown. I would also like it so have a set time. I am stuck trying to convert the number of seconds in the countdown to Days:Hours:Minutes:Seconds and I don't know how to connect that conversion to a GUI. I am thinking I could possibly use a JLabel but I am not sure.

I have this code so far that I found on another forum.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS;

public class Countdown {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

        final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            int countdownStarter = 20;

            public void run() {

                System.out.println(countdownStarter);
                countdownStarter--;

                if (countdownStarter < 0) {
                    System.out.println("Timer Over!");
                    scheduler.shutdown();
                }
            }
        };
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 1, SECONDS);
    }
}
```

It counts down from 20 at the moment which you can change by changing

```
int countdownStarter = 20;
```

I have noticed that there is a

```
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.DAYS;
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.HOURS;
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MINUTES;
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS;
```

That can be used in the code I have so far. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I am not looking for a substitute application to use instead.

Comment: "_convert the number of seconds in the countdown to Days:Hours:Minutes:Seconds_" One approach - take a look at [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#ofSeconds-long-), and the various methods it has to extract different duration units such as `toHours()`, `toDays()`.

Comment: Do not use ScheduledExecutorService.  GUIs require the use of a particular thread, and using an arbitrary thread of your own is not compatible with them.  If you are planning to use Swing for your GUI, use [javax.swing.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Timer.html) (*not* java.util.Timer!).  If you are planning to use JavaFX for your GUI, use [ScheduledService](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update a JLabel text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456401/how-to-update-a-jlabel-text)

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

You seem to be working much too hard here. I found your code hard to follow, and likely overwrought. Java has an industry-leading date-time framework in the *java.time* classes, defined in JSR 310. Make use of that.

## Use `javax.swing.Timer`, not your own threads

As others commented, for a Swing app, you should be using the [`javax.swing.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Timer.html) class (or [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)) rather than counting down in your own threads and executor service. See [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) by Oracle.

## Tracking time to elapse

As to your specific question about determining the days, hours, minutes, seconds, and nanos remaining before a particular moment:

- Decide whether you want to track your span of time (a) by calendar days or, (b) by generic 24-hour chunked “days”.
- Store your target moment.
- Capture the current moment.
- Calculate elapsed time.

I will assume you want 24-hour chunked days rather than calendar days.

The `Instant` class represents a moment, a specific point on the timeline, as seen in UTC (an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds).

The `Duration` class represents a span of time unattached to the timeline, on a scale of 24-hour generic days, hours, minutes, seconds, and nanos.

```
Duration week = Duration.ofDays( 7 ) ;  // 7 * 24 hours = 1 week, ignoring calendar, ignoring time zones.
Instant target = Instant.now().plus( week ) ;
```

When your timer task runs, capture the current moment, and calculate time remaining.

```
Duration timeRemaining = Duration.between( Instant.now() , target ) ;
```

Check to see if the remaining duration [is positive](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#isPositive()) or [is negative](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#isNegative()).

- If positive, the target is still in the future. So report its current value.
- If negative, the target has passed. So recalculate the next target, the next week out. And report the new value.

### Example code

Here is a class to track the repeating weekly countdown.

```java
package work.basil.example.time;

import java.time.*;

public class Weekly
{
    private final Duration week = Duration.ofDays( 7 );
    private Instant target = Instant.now().plus( week );

    public Duration timeRemaining ( )
    {
        Duration timeRemaining = Duration.between( Instant.now() , target );
        if ( timeRemaining.isNegative() )  // If the current moment is *after* the target, calculate a new target.
        {
            target = target.plus( week );
            timeRemaining = Duration.between( Instant.now() , target );
        }
        return timeRemaining;
    }
}
```

If you want to report on the next target moment, add a `getter` method that returns an `Instant`. The *java.time* objects such as `Instant` are [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), so no need to make a copy when returning.

Here is some code to exercise that `Weekly` class. The `Weekly#timeRemaining` method is what your `SwingTimer` code will call.

```java
Weekly weekly = new Weekly();

Duration duration = weekly.timeRemaining() ;
System.out.println( duration );

try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 3 ) ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException( e ); }
System.out.println( weekly.timeRemaining() );
try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 30 ) ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException( e ); }
System.out.println( weekly.timeRemaining() );
try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofMinutes( 5 ) ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException( e ); }
System.out.println( weekly.timeRemaining() );
```

When run:

```
PT167H59M59.999799S
PT167H59M56.994437S
PT167H59M26.989259S
PT167H54M26.987014S
```

### Generate text

Lastly, you want to generate text to represent this countdown value.

You can interrogate the `Duration` objects for its parts, a number of generic 24-hour days (not related to the calendar), hours, minutes, seconds, and nanos. Use the various `to…Part` methods on the [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) class.

```
long days = duration.toDaysPart() ;
int hours = duration.toHoursPart() ;
int minutes = duration.toMinutesPart() ;
int seconds = duration.toSecondsPart() ;
```

Combine those [numbers together as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6431933/642706).

```
String output = 
    String.format(
        "Time remaining: %d days, %d hours,  %d minutes,  %d seconds", 
        days, 
        hours, 
        minutes, 
        seconds 
    ) 
;
```

> Time remaining: 6 days, 23 hours,  59 minutes,  59 seconds

Display that text in your [JLabel](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JLabel.html) widget. [See tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) by Oracle.

```
myJLabel.setText( output ) ;
```

## Example app

Here is a complete example Swing app.

```java
package work.basil.example.time;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;

public class WeeklySwingApp
{
    // Code modified from example app provided by Oracle Corp at:
    // https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/start/HelloWorldSwingProject/src/start/HelloWorldSwing.java
    private static void createAndShowGUI ( )
    {
        Weekly weekly = new Weekly();

        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame( "Weekly Countdown" );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

        //Add the ubiquitous "Hello World" label.
        JLabel label = new JLabel( "Time remaining: …" );
        frame.getContentPane().add( label );

        // Countdown.
        int delay = 1_000; // milliseconds
        ActionListener taskPerformer = ( ActionEvent actionEvent ) -> label.setText( formatTimeRemaining( weekly.timeRemaining() ) );
        new Timer( delay , taskPerformer ).start();

        //Display the window.
        frame.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 420 , 100 ) );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    private static String formatTimeRemaining ( final Duration duration )
    {
        return String.format(
                "Time remaining: %d days, %d hours,  %d minutes,  %d seconds" ,
                duration.toDaysPart() ,
                duration.toHoursPart() ,
                duration.toMinutesPart() ,
                duration.toSecondsPart()
        );
    }
    
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {public void run ( ) { createAndShowGUI(); }} );
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot of example app displaying a JLabel with countdown text]

Comment: This actually helps out a bunch and went really in depth for what I was trying to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As you have already noticed, you can use the TimeUnit class to perform the conversions. Here is an example:

```
int seconds = 3600;
int day = (int)TimeUnit.SECONDS.toDays(seconds);
long hours = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(seconds) - (day * 24);
long minute = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(seconds) - (TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(seconds)* 60);
long second = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(seconds) - (TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(seconds) *60);
System.out.println(day + ":" + hours + ":" + minute + ":" + second);
```

on regards to the ouput possibilities, that depends on how you want to display it. JFrame, Terminal, something else.